# How to store premium content buy status locally in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, in-app-purchase

Let's say I have a list with 15 list items and I only want to offer 5 of those as free and I want to offer the rest as premium content. So I have a few options -

1) Create 2 apps - free and paid. Offer free content in free and all content in paid.

2) Add authentication and use online database like Firestore to know whether or not user has bought premium content, if yes then show all content in app, if not then only show free part.

I don't want to implement any of the above 2 solutions as my app does not need authentication and I don't want to add it just for the sake of premium content. So I want to add a solution which works locally.

The first time user installs the app, they will be able to view free content, i.e first 5 items and then once they scroll, they get message "Buy to unlock the rest". I believe Shared Preferences won't be a good fit because if user resets app data in Settings, the premium version which the user bought will be gone.

So what should I use to check and store whether or not the user has made an in app purchase for premium content or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firebase Anonymous login to achieve this. Thus, the user don't sign-in explicitly with user id and password or like and yet you get the user id. You can use this user id to store the purchased content information in the Firestore.

An alternative is to use device id.  You can use package [device_info](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info). It gives a unique device id which you can use to identify the user.  The following code snippet will retrieve the unique id for the device.

```
final DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfoPlugin = new DeviceInfoPlugin();

if (Platform.isAndroid) 
  {
    var build = await deviceInfoPlugin.androidInfo;
    identifier = build.androidId;             // Android Device id 
  } else if (Platform.isIOS) 
  {

    var data = await deviceInfoPlugin.iosInfo;

    identifier = data.identifierForVendor;    //UUID for iOS
  }
```

In both the cases above, there's no local data storage.

Note : If user changes the device then he/she won't be able to access the premium content. The sign-in will solve this problem and can get the content bought on one device accessible on other. And you can always control number of 'active' devices per user.

Comment: So is there no offline storage to manage in app purchases? Clearing app data in settings will clear everything stored offline, right?